# Show Multi-list selected items on view by glass mapper

Tags: sitecore-api

I am able to get `Guid` of seleced items by Glass Mapper but i don't know how i can get those item by Id and show them on view.

Glass mapper property that i am using is:

```
[SitecoreField("Media Links")]
public virtual string MediaLinks { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

What about mapping them directly to an Object instead of a string?

Something like this:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<MyItem> { get; set; }
```

Comment: @Rakesh don't forget to accept this answer if you think it helped you solve the original problem.